# Multiple stores in Magento 1.7. Not directing to new website

Tags: magento-1.7

Multiple stores in Magento 1.7. 
I am having issues setting this up. 
I have set up via configuration two websites, store, store views etc and the url's in web config. 
I have changed the A records on the domain to point to the magento website and I have as instructed changed index.php but when i type in my 2nd website address it just takes me to the main (original) website pages, if I change the default website in Magento it works! I can't be far off but I'm struggling now, any advice?
I've been told that in 1.7 I only need to alter index.php to make it work
Andrew

Comment: what have you added to your index.php file?

Answer (score 0):

you must provide either store code or website code to server variable $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] or as first parameter to Mage::run() function in index.php file, for example if every subdomain of site has one store, you can accomplish this by:

```
$storeOrWebsiteCode = strtok($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'.');
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = $storeOrWebsiteCode;
```

or

```
$storeOrWebsiteCode = strtok($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'.');
Mage::run($storeOrWebsiteCode, 'website');
or
Mage::run($storeOrWebsiteCode, 'store');
```